# How to use a short script to eliminate all but one duplicate column variables based on the prefix of the colname

Tags: r, automation, duplicates

I want to know to use a short script to eliminate all but one duplicate column variables based on the prefix of the colname without inputting the variables I want to remove by hand.

For example, I created repeats of the `mtcars$am` variables, called `am1`, `am2`, `am3`, and `am4` in a data frame called `mtcars_example_2`. I removed the original `am` variable in the `mtcars_example_2` data frame.

I can use the script below to eliminate all variables with the prefix "am" but the `am1` variable into a new variable called `mtcars_example_3` using the code below, which inputs all variables to remove by hand:

```
## long way of removing all variable with am prefix that were not am1
mtcars_example_3 <- 
  mtcars_example_2 %>% 
  select(
    -c(
      "am2", "am3", "am4"
    )
  )
```

But this seems like the long way of doing this. Is there a faster way that does not require me to individual type in the names of each of the variables that I want to remove from the data.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Thanks ahead of time.

---

---

Here is the code for the example:

```
# example data

## loads packages
library(tidyverse)

## creates mtcars_example data
mtcars_example_1 <- data.frame(mtcars)
mtcars_example_2 <- data.frame(mtcars_example_1)

## creates duplicate variables, based on am variable
mtcars_example_2$am1 <- mtcars_example_1$am
mtcars_example_2$am2 <- mtcars_example_1$am
mtcars_example_2$am3 <- mtcars_example_1$am
mtcars_example_2$am4 <- mtcars_example_1$am

## removes original variable
mtcars_example_2 <- 
  mtcars_example_2 %>% 
  select(
    -c(
      "am"
    )
  )

## long way of removing all variable with am prefix that were not am1
mtcars_example_3 <- 
  mtcars_example_2 %>% 
  select(
    -c(
      "am2", "am3", "am4"
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the variables that start with `am` but keep `am1` :

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars_example_2 %>% select(-starts_with('am'), am1) %>% head 

#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb am1
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0    4    4   1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0    4    4   1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1    4    1   1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1    3    1   0
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0    3    2   0
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1    3    1   0
```

Depending on your actual scenario you can also use regex to remove columns.

```
mtcars_example_2 %>% select(-matches('am[2-4]')) %>% head
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars_example_2 %>%
     select(-contains('am'), am1)
```